# Image Resize - Jquery UI not working on web page, but jsFiddle works - other methods? - for contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, contenteditable, image-resizing

Working in contenteditable with images.  Want to be able to have images with one drag handle on the bottom right to allow the user to resize dynamically.  I see this in many of these html editors, so there must be some standard approach that works... PLEASE POINT ME IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION (Jquery preferred, but can be other).

**WHAT I FOUND:**
older posts of people using Jquery UI successfully.  I tried the same at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hderr/8badm7rj/10/) and achieved the same results in the fiddle - IT WORKS and has a BOTTOM RIGHT drag handle!  I noticed it uses rather old versions of Jquery and Jquery UI.  I suspect there may be problems using it with the latest version of Jquery as selecting newer versions on the fiddle made the Jquery UI choices dissappear?

I tried the exact same code on my web page, with Jquery 1.91, Jquery UI 1.92, matching the fiddle, but did not work on my page.  It was missing the bottom right pull tab to resize. WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE?

I also tried using the latest Jquery:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

But that did not make any difference.  The code matching the fiddle is below (not working on my page, no drag handle).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-e9gNBsAcA0DBuRWbm0oZfbiCyhjLrI6bmqAl5o+ZjUA="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"
      integrity="sha256-PsB+5ZEsBlDx9Fi/GXc1bZmC7wEQzZK4bM/VwNm1L6c="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>  
     <script>
        $('#image').resizable();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="image" style="border: 5px solid black;" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Same result in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE.

EDIT: Per Tushar's solution of including the CSS, I have tried it out and it still does not produce the pull tab... see below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" style="border: 5px solid black;" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />    
</body>
</html>
```

Oops!  forgot to add the script, it works fine after that:

```
<script>$('#image').resizable();</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the jquery-ui CSS, try adding and it would work.

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

PS: Make sure you have the right version CSS matching your js file for jQuery-ui.

- updated with CDN link

```js
$('#image').resizable();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img id="image" style="border: 5px solid black;" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
```

Comment: Ah... I believe your are right as your example snippet works!  However, the CSS link you used returned a "file not found" on my end... So I used another cdn:  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css - though the system loaded it, I still did not get the pull tab symbol... hmmm....?  Can you try it with this cdn please?

Comment: yep, I have updated it in my example and works.

Comment: make sure you have `jquery-ui` after `jQuery`

Comment: I add exactly what you have and still did not get the pull tabs showing up.  See my edit in my code above in the question update.

Comment: forgot to add the script, works fine after that.  Thanks!  <script>$('#image').resizable();</script>